# Is this true for real numbers?

Tags: absolute-value

$|a_{m+1}b_{m+1}+a_{m+2}b_{m+2}...a_nb_n|<|a_{m+1}(b+1)+a_{m+2}(b+1)+...+a_n(b+1)|$

Is this true if we know that $b_n<b+1$ for any $n$? I am not sure, I would appreciate any help. I think it's true from the triangle inequality but i might be wrong.

Comment: No, it's not true. $|(-1)(-1)+1(1)|>|(-1)(2)+(1)(2)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all.  For instance, $-1<0$, but $|1\cdot (-1)|<|1\cdot 0|$ is false.  Or if you want the $b$'s to be nonnegative, a counterexample is $$|(-1)\cdot 2+1\cdot 1|\not<|(-1)\cdot 3+1\cdot 3|.$$

Comment: Wait is it true if |b_n|<b+1 though? From the triangle inequality.

Comment: No, see my second counterexample.

Comment: $|a_{m+1}b_{m+1}+a_{m+2}b_{m+2}...a_nb_n|<|a_{m+1}b_{m+1}|+...+|a_nb_n|=|b_{m+1}||a_{m+1}|+...+|a_n||b_n|$ And since $|b_n|<b+1$ then clearly, we get $<(b+1)(|a_{m+1}|+...+|a_n|)$

Comment: Where is my mistake?

Comment: You have no mistake, but the right-hand side of that inequality is not the same as what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Oh wow, you are right, my bad. Sorry. Thanks for the help